# AccessDenied when generate signed url for Amazon s3 using aws-cloudfront-sign and node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

[image: Here is the signed url in PostMan]I created a bucket on s3 and added a HTML file, after this I created a Cloud Front key pair using my root user and added a Cloud Front Distribution for that bucket. Tried to access the object using that distribution and it worked, than I restricted access to the bucket using Behaviour and selected "self". 
Finally I generated a signed url from node js and tested it using Postman.
The problem is that I always get AccessDenied.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

Here is my code.

```
const cfsign = require("aws-cloudfront-sign");

var signingParams = {
    keypairId: process.env.PUBLIC_KEY,
    privateKeyPath: "./aws/Y3PA.pem",
    expireTime: (new Date().getTime() + 999999999)
};

// Generating a signed URL
signedUrl = () => {
    console.log("url created " + process.env.PUBLIC_KEY);

    return cfsign.getSignedUrl(
        "xxxx.cloudfront.net/test.html",
        signingParams
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme is part of the URL that is required as [input to the signature algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-canned-policy.html), so your error is lilely to be here:

```
cfsign.getSignedUrl("xxxx.cloudfront.net/...
```

Instead of that, you need this:

```
cfsign.getSignedUrl("https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/...
```